# Binary Search and Hashtable Search

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashtable, binary-search

I wanted to find out the trade off point between a Dictionary lookup and a binary search lookup of an array. I was expecting constant time lookups for the Dictionary, and logarithmic time lookups for the binary search depending on the size of the collection, with the binary search performing better for smaller sized collections.

However, I was surprised when I saw the following results:
[image: Binary search growing exponentially, and hash lookup growing slowly]

I was surprised at: 1. Binary search is growing logarithmically at first, and then grows much faster. 2. Hash is pretty consistent at first, but then also starts growing slowly. 3. Binary search is never better than the hash lookup. Below is my code. What did I do wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var targets = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1000).Select(_ => r.Next(int.MaxValue)).ToList();

        for (int totalCount = 1; totalCount < 1000*1000*10; totalCount*=2)
        {
            var a = Enumerable.Range(0, totalCount).Select(_ => r.Next(int.MaxValue)).Distinct().Select(v => new thing(v)).OrderBy(t => t.value).ToArray();
            var d = a.ToDictionary(t => t.value);

            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            {
                watch.Start();
                var found = targets.Select(t => BinarySearch(t, a)).Where(t => t != null).Count();
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("found {0} things out of {2} in {1} ms with binary search", found, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, a.Length));
            }
            {
                watch.Restart();
                var found =  targets.Select(t => HashSearch(t, d)).Where(t => t != null).Count();
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("found {0} things out of {2} in {1} ms with hash search", found, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, d.Keys.Count));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static thing HashSearch(int needle, Dictionary<int, thing> hash)
    {
        if (!hash.ContainsKey(needle))
            return null;
        return hash[needle];
    }

    static thing BinarySearch(int needle, thing[] sortedHaystack)
    {
        return BinarySearch(needle, sortedHaystack, 0, sortedHaystack.Length - 1);
    }
    static thing BinarySearch(int needle, thing[] sortedHaystack, int minimum, int maximum)
    {
        if (minimum > maximum)
            return null;
        var middle = (minimum + maximum) / 2;
        if (needle == sortedHaystack[middle].value)
            return sortedHaystack[middle];
        if (needle < sortedHaystack[middle].value)
            return BinarySearch(needle, sortedHaystack, minimum, middle - 1);
        return BinarySearch(needle, sortedHaystack, middle + 1, maximum);
    }

    class thing
    {
        public int value;
        public thing(int v)
        {
            value = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's surprising you, exactly? The fact that the dictionary search isn't perfectly constant? Or the fact that the dictionary wins even for small collections? Note that by iterating over a large list, you'll end up with a lot of cache misses *just for the iteration*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point. I've clarified my question with what's surprising to me.

Comment: I wouldn't say that binary search is growing exponentially - at least, it's not *obviously* doing so, given that your x axis is a log axis. Plot it against a linear x axis and it may well be significantly clearer. The rest may be explained just through cache misses, to be honest - the bigger the collection, the more cache misses you'll get even with a notionally constant-time lookup.

Comment: (To put it another way: the time complexity calculations of these lookups generally assume that each memory read is equally costly. That's not the case when some reads miss the cache and others don't.)

Comment: @JonSkeet you're way too fast. I fixed the the exponential part right after my comment. The caching issue would explain why both algorithms start slowing down around the same point.

Comment: Right. So that leaves the "why is binary search the same speed as hash for a single item collection" - at which point again I think the fact that you're iterating over a huge list is messing with your results, because again you'll have cache misses which I suspect will dwarf everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Pretty much as noted in comments.)

I suspect you're mostly seeing the effects of cache misses. When the collection is large, you'll get a lot of cache misses - particularly with the binary search, which potentially needs to touch a lot of points in the collection to find an element.

At the low sizes, I suspect you're seeing cache misses too, but this time on your `targets` list - and also the overhead of LINQ itself. LINQ is fast, but it can still be significant when all you're doing is performing a single search of a tiny collection in the middle.

I'd suggest rewriting your loops to something like:

```
{
    // Use the same seed each time for consistency. Doesn't have to be 0.
    Random random = new Random(0);
    watch.Start();
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
    {
        if (BinarySearch(t, random.Next(int.MaxValue)) != null)
        {
            found++;
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format
         "found {0} things out of {2} in {1} ms with binary search",
         found, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, a.Length));
}
```

Of course you've then got the problem of including random number generation in the loop instead... you might want to look at using a random number generator which is faster than `System.Random` if you can find one. Or use some other way of determining which elements to look up.

Oh, and I'd personally rewrite the binary search to use iteration rather than recursion, but that's a different matter. I wouldn't expect it to have a significant effect.

Comment: As you predicted, iterative binary search did not have a significant effect.

Comment: @JonSkeet `and I'd personally rewrite the binary search to use iteration rather than recursion` Why?

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui: Why take up stack for no reason? There's no benefit in recursing here - a looped binary search is dead easy to write, and has less risk of stack overflow.