# Collection of objects with two keys

Tags: c#, collections

Imagine this scenario: I need to manipulate (add, search and delete) items from a list of objects of type `Book`.

```
class Book{
 int Id {get; set;}
 string Title {get; set;}
 string Author {get; set;}
 int Year {get; set;}
 // more properties
}
```

Constriants:

- `Id` should be unique within the collection of `Books`
- `Title` should be unique within the collection of `Books`

What I have so far, a `Dictionary<int, Book>` that has `Id` as a key and `Book` as a value. But in this case, If I want to add a new book to the dictionary I have to loop through all the values to check whether the `Title` is duplicate or not.

I start thinking about creating a `HashSet` only for Titles or having a second dictionary `Dictionary<string, Book>` that has `Title` as a key.

Any suggestion How to handle this scenario?

**Edit:**

As @David mentioned, I forgot to tell that my main concern here is performance. I want to lookup objects by Id and Title in the fastest way (O(1)).

Comment: I don't see any better option .. another dictionary if lookup by title is needed, or HashSet if not

Comment: Maximum I could think (but it will not be as optimized as you want) is you make key of Dictionary as `<"id"> + "-" +<"string">` , then instead of checking `if(Dict.ContainsKey(<key>))` check `if(!(Dict.Keys.Any(x => x.Split("-".ToCharArray())[0] == newKey.Split("-".ToCharArray())[0] 
                || x.Split("-".ToCharArray())[1] == newKey.Split("-".ToCharArray())[1])))` where `newKey` is again `<"id> + "-" + <"name">` but for new entry.

Comment: Dictionary lookup isn't `O(1)`, it's `O(log n)`. If you want `O(1)` you need to use an array.

Comment: What are your concerns about using two dictionaries? It *would* probably perform best when looking for either `Id` *or* `Title`. The cost of space should be negligible, since the dictionaries only store references to the actual instances of the `Book` class. So you'd only need `numberOfBooks * sizeOf(reference)` plus a little overhead for the dictionary and maybe the keys more space. -- You might want to create a wrapper like `DoubleKeyedDictionary<TKeyA, TKeyB, TValue>` which keeps the two separate dictionaries organized/synchronized (adding, removing, acces by key, etc.).

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Dictionary/HashTable lookup is "[close to O(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks)" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374092/binary-search-and-hashtable-search

Answer (score 2):

You might use Tuple as the key:

```
var collection = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, Book> (...);
var key = new Tuple<int, string>(1, "David");  // <<-----------
if(!collection.ContainsKey(key))
    collection [key] = new Book(...);
```

Note that Tuple has its built in [Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346(v=vs.110).aspx) to make your life easier.

---

Update:

@AustinWBryan mentioned using ValueTuples (C# 7.0 feature) to replace Tuple, highly recommended. For more info about ValueTuples, refer to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/).

Comment: Very clever and elegant! Though I prefer the ValueTuples. I think `Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, Book>` isn't as clean as `Dictionar<(int, string), Book>`.

Comment: Tuple will not resolve performance issue I'm concerned about: If I want to look up a book by Title, I still have to  loop through all the keys and check if Tuple.item2 == "title"

Comment: @Mhd, where did you mention your memory concern in the OP?

Comment: @Mhd, you don't have to loop. LINQ is your friend!

Comment: @David I think I need  to edit my OP to make emphasis on performance.  I'm aware of LINQ and I could use Contains but still is O(N) operation (to em it is a loop) and not O(1) like a look up for dictionary

Comment: the constraint is that id and title have to be unique in the collection separately, not together

Comment: As @Slai pointed out, Tuple will not help as we can add dulicate IDs and Titles. Having two keys (1, "David") and (1, "Mhd") is not acceptable

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that both sides of the composite key are also unique a tuple won't cut it. Instead make your own key that checks for this in the equality checker.

```
public struct CompositeKey<T1, T2> : IEquatable<CompositeKey<T1, T2>>
{
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T1> t1Comparer = EqualityComparer<T1>.Default;
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T2> t2Comparer = EqualityComparer<T2>.Default;

    public T1 Key1;
    public T2 Key2;

    public CompositeKey(T1 key1, T2 key2)
    {
        Key1 = key1;
        Key2 = key2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is CompositeKey<T1, T2> && Equals((CompositeKey<T1, T2>)obj);

    public bool Equals(CompositeKey<T1, T2> other)
    {
        return t1Comparer.Equals(Key1, other.Key1)
            && t2Comparer.Equals(Key2, other.Key2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Key1.GetHashCode();
}
```

So the dictionary works on buckets. It puts all the keys into buckets based on the hash code generated by `GetHashCode()`. Then it searches that bucket using a for loop over `Equals()`. The idea is that buckets should be as small as possible (ideally one item).

So we can control when a key will match, and how many buckets/items there are by controlling the hash code. If we return a constant hash code like 0, then everything is in the same bucket and it's down to the equality method to compare every item.

This comparer only returns the hash of the first key item. Assuming the first key item should be unique this is enough. Each bucket should still be one item, and when doing a lookup (that uses the full equals method) that's when the second key is also checked to ensure the type is the same value.

If you want to use `ValueTuple` as the key type you can pass in a custom comparer to the dictionary to achieve the same effect.

```
public class CompositeValueTupleComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<(T1, T2)>
{
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T1> t1Comparer = EqualityComparer<T1>.Default;
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T2> t2Comparer = EqualityComparer<T2>.Default;

    public bool Equals((T1, T2) x, (T1, T2) y) => 
        t1Comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1) && t2Comparer.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2);

    public int GetHashCode((T1, T2) obj) => obj.Item1.GetHashCode();
}

new Dictionary<(int, string), Book>(new CompositeValueTupleComparer<int, string>());
```

Comment: I don't see how this would prevent the dictionary in adding a compositeKey to a dictionary which already have another key with the same T2 value(book with the same title).
From what I can see this wouldn't even prevent the dictionary from having duplicate T1 values (book ID's).
Actually forgot about not seeing it, I copied it to test it out. The only thing this does is working as a tuple key (other than giving all books with the same Id the same hash meaning they will end in the same bucket).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like both the `ID` and `Name` are going to be unique, as in, you shouldn't be able to use the same ID twice, regardless if the name has been used already. Otherwise, we'd end up with `dict[3]` referring to two different values.

Tuples or structs can't give that behavior, and still require you to loop. What you should instead do, is use a class similar to the one I've created:

```
public class TwoKeyDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>
{
    public readonly List<TKey1> firstKeys  = new List<TKey1>();
    public readonly List<TKey2> secondKeys = new List<TKey2>();
    public readonly List<TValue> values    = new List<TValue>();


    public void Add(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TValue value)
    {
        if (firstKeys.Contains(key1))  throw new ArgumentException();
        if (secondKeys.Contains(key2)) throw new ArgumentException();

        firstKeys.Add(key1);
        secondKeys.Add(key2);
        values.Add(value);
    }

    public void Remove(TKey1 key) => RemoveAll(firstKeys.IndexOf(key));
    public void Remove(TKey2 key) => RemoveAll(secondKeys.IndexOf(key));
    private void RemoveAll(int index)
    {
        if (index < 1) return;

        firstKeys.RemoveAt(index);
        secondKeys.RemoveAt(index);
        values.RemoveAt(index);
    }


    public TValue this[TKey1 key1]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = firstKeys.IndexOf(key1);
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            return values[firstKeys.IndexOf(key1)];
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey2 key2]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = secondKeys.IndexOf(key2);
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            return values[secondKeys.IndexOf(key2)];
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var twoDict = new TwoKeyDictionary<int, string, float>();
twoDict.Add(0, "a", 0.5f);
twoDict.Add(2, "b", 0.25f);

Console.WriteLine(twoDict[0]);     // Prints "0.5"
Console.WriteLine(twoDict[2]);     // Prints "0.25"
Console.WriteLine(twoDict["a"]);   // Prints "0.5"
Console.WriteLine(twoDict["b"]);   // Prints "0.25"

twoDict.Add(0, "d", 2);            // Throws exception: 0 has already been added, even though "d" hasn't
twoDict.Add(1, "a", 5);            // Throws exception: "a" has already been added, even though "1" hasn't
```

The `TwoKeyDictionary` would need to implement `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, etc., to do the full behavior stuff

Comment: constructor is checking for both `firstKeys.Contains()` and `secondKeys.Contains()` separately, will it be **(O(1))** complexity ?

Comment: First, that's not the constructor, that's the method to add a new element, but also, wouldn't it have to? I mean, I could use a boolean operator and to make it one `if` statement, but that's not gonna change whether it's an O(1) or O(n), and it does need to check both to get the desired behavior. I have no idea how C# handles that method but lists are supposed to be really optimized so I think the lists would have to be an impressive size before it starts slowing things down.

Comment: Of course it is a method, my bad there. And yes i agree OP's requirement is quite an odd to be fitted in O(1). if you have used Boolean and in `if` you check for both of the lists, it is as good as what you have shown here.  In practical your approach is very much less likely to create a problem (if data is huge then its different matter). But still answer is not as optimized as OP needs it to be.

Comment: That's good to know. O(log n) is the second fastest (at larger sizes) second only to O(1) itself and it accelerates slower and slower as the size gets bigger. O(n) which is what a for loop is is two orders higher, so it is higher optimized and gives that double-key behavior. The only way to get O(1) is to use arrays which can't have remove or add elements like he is going to need, and creating a new array and reallocating all that memory each time is going to be more consuming than just using a `List`. At some point you're gonna have to sacrifice performance (not that much) to get the job done